# multiplying int and double in recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, int, double

In the following program, the user enters `a` for how many hours they've worked, and `b` for their hourly rate, then it calculates their pay.

It was working when both `a` and `b` were type `int`, then I realized my teacher asked for `b` to be a double.

I tried changing everything for `b` from `int` to `double`, but now it is returning an error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project61 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the amount of hours first and then the hourly rate");
      int a=in.nextInt();
      double b=in.nextDouble();
      double res = mult (a, b);
      System.out.println("Hours : "+ a);
      System.out.println("Rate per hour : "+ "$"+ b);
      System.out.println("Pay : "+ "$" +res);
  }

  public static double mult(int a, double b) {

      if(b ==1){
          return a;
      }
      if (b<1) {
          return -a + mult(a, b+1);
      }
      else{
          return a + mult(a, b-1);
      }
   }


}
```

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError. Then it repeatedly says the error is at line 26 and 29. Which is the return -a + mult(a, b+1); and return a + mult(a, b-1);

Comment: You most likely will want to put in a condition for the case b > 1, since b is now a double it could be greater be a non-whole number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, if `b` is not equal to an integer (for instance, if `b == 2.5`), you will *never* get 1 by repeatedly subtracting 1 from it. So your recursive function will call itself with `b == 1.5`, then with `b == 0.5`, then again with `b == 1.5`, ad infinitum (or at least, ad untilum Javaum runsum outum ofum stackum memoryum). You need to create an exit case that you can guarantee will be triggered eventually.

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert int a to double. You can not multiply double with integer. You could convert int a to double after input or just in

```
method public static double mult(int a, double b) 
{
  double aa = a.doubleValue();

      if(b ==1)
      {
          return a;
      }
      if (b<1) 
      {
          return -aa + mult(aa, b+1);
      }
      else
      {
          return aa + mult(aa, b-1);
      }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `StackOverflowError` he said he was getting, and also isn't correct: if you try to pass `aa` (a `double`) into `mult` as the first parameter `a` (an `int`) without casting, you'll get a compiler error.